# Write A Card Game

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, playing-cards

I wish to write a card game for Windows Mobile 6 using .Net C#. Is there a good managed library that I can use that contain cards? e.g. the images, the deck etc. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[The first SVG cards deck ever created](http://david.bellot.free.fr/svg-cards/)

Comment: how can this be used in MS Visual Studio.Net 2008 (C#)?